# How to print directly to a printer connected to serial port via .net desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, printing, serial-port, desktop-application

I've been working on a desktop application built using .NET Framework 4.5 and C# as language. Requirement is that a printer will be connected on serial port, port settings will be provided by user through the application like port number, baud rate etc. etc.

When user hits a print button, it should directly print to the printer without showing a print dialogue.
I've never done printing from desktop application and i've no idea how to achieve this.

1. Should i have to code specific to driver of that printer?
2. Or is there any generic way to send print instructions to printer connected to serial port?
3. I can send normal string to serial port, but what if i need to do some formatting like drawing a table, how can i make a serial port printer printing a formatted table and values inside it ... for example a bill.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

You will want to send ESC/POS commands. This will control the font, line height, etc. as well as the actual text being transmitted.

http://pyramidacceptors.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ESC_POS_Protocol_Commands_REV_B.pdf

Another userful SO question: [How to use esc/pos command with c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349599/how-to-use-esc-pos-command-with-c)

Also, no need to reinvent the wheel. Check Github for a library: https://github.com/yukimizake/ThermalDotNet

As far as generating tables and other such non-text, you'll want to read up on the command set supported by your target printer. If you're printing a bill, it sounds like you are targeting a thermal printer. Image/non-text support will vary from model to model.

Comment: that library works very well. a simple change to add QR code printing

Comment: i will try that as well.... wish i could modified the simpler one.